# On a limit exercise $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ln \Big( \frac{\sin x e^{x/ (x+1)} - x}{x \sin x} \Big)/ \arctan x $.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to solve this limit

$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \ln \Big( \frac{\sin x e^{x/ (x+1)} - x}{x \sin x} \Big)/ \arctan x $$

So this is what I did:

$$\Bigg( \frac{\sin x e^{x/ (x+1)} - x}{x \sin x} \Bigg) = \Bigg( \frac{ (x -1/6x^3 + o(x^3)) (1+ x/(x+1) + (x/2(x+1))^2 + o(x^2)) - x}{x \sin x} \Bigg)$$

$$= \Bigg( \frac{x^2 (x+1) 6 +3x^3 - x^3 (x+1)^2 + o(x^3)}{(x+1)^2 6 x^2(1 -1/6 x^2 + o(x^2)   )} \Bigg) = \Bigg( \frac{1+ 4/3x +o(x)}{(x+1)^2 (1 -1/6 x^2 + o(x^2)   )} \Bigg) $$

So now $$\ln \Big( \frac{\sin x e^{x/ (x+1)} - x}{x \sin x} \Big) = \ln(1+ 4/3x +o(x)) -\ln(x+1)^2 - \ln(1 -1/6 x^2 + o(x^2))   $$

and if I expand the arctan and these logs with Taylor I obtain that the limit is equal to $4/3$ except the limit should be equal to $-2/3$.

When I taylor expand first in the exponent of $e ^{x / (x+1)}$  I get the correct result, but what I am doing above should be correct too right?

Could someone kindly tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: You might have mistakenly used that, since $\ln(1+ ax +o(x))=ax+o(x)$ with $a=4/3$, $$A(x)=\ln(1+ ax +o(x)) -\ln(x+1)^2 - \ln(1 -1/6 x^2 + o(x^2))$$ is $$A(x)=ax+o(x)$$ while actually, $\ln(1+x)^2=2\ln(1+x)=2x+o(x)$ hence $$A(x) =ax+o(x)-(2x+o(x))-o(x)=(a-2)x+o(x).  $$ Note that, after this step, expanding arctan is not needed, simply use $\arctan x\sim x$.

Answer (score -1):

Using theorem of arithmetic borders:
$$\lim_{x→0}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\sin x \exp\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)-x}{x\sin x}\right)}{\arctan x}=\lim_{x→0}\frac{\ln\left(\sin x \exp\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)-x\right)-\ln\left(x\sin x\right)}{\arctan x}$$
We calculating more simply limit:
$$\lim_{x→0} \frac{1}{\arctan x}=\frac{1}{\arctan 0}=\frac{1}{0}=\infty$$
Now we calculating limit:
$$\lim_{x→0}\frac{\ln\left(\sin x \exp\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)-x\right)-\ln\left(x\sin x\right)}{\arctan x}=\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]=\lim_{x→0}\frac{\left(\ln\left(\sin x \exp\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)-x\right)-\ln\left(x\sin x\right)\right)^\prime}{\left(\arctan x\right)^\prime}=\lim_{x→0}\frac{\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\sin x-x}\left(-\frac{\left(\exp\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\sin x-x\right)\csc x}{x^2}+\frac{\csc x\left(\exp\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{x}{\left(x+1\right)^2}\right)\sin x+
\exp\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\cos x-1\right)}{x}-\frac{\left(\exp\left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)\sin x-x\right)\cot x\csc x}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x^2+1}}=\frac{\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{0}{0+1}\right)\sin 0-0}\left(-\frac{\left(\exp\left(\frac{0}{0+1}\right)\sin 0-0\right)\csc 0}{0^2}+\frac{\csc 0\left(\exp\left(\frac{0}{0+1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{0+1}-\frac{0}{\left(0+1\right)^2}\right)\sin 0+
\exp\left(\frac{0}{0+1}\right)\cos 0-1\right)}{0}-\frac{\left(\exp\left(\frac{0}{0+1}\right)\sin 0-0\right)\cot 0\csc 0}{0}\right)}{\frac{1}{0^2+1}}=\frac{-\frac{2}{3}}{\frac{1}{1}}=-\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Unfortunately, in general, $$\log\left(\frac{a}b\right)\ne\frac{\log a}b.$$

Comment: I will edit this answer.

Comment: A very good example showing why L'Hopital is not always the way to go (it is very seldom, but let us leave it at that).

Comment: By the way, it is not quite clear how the limit $-\frac23$ pops up from the monster expression just before. Care to explain?